# Cordova Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'require' of undefined

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

All,

Could you please help me with following. I am trying to access the camera API using cordova. I have created the project using cordova cli. My config.xml has this option added to allow the camera plugin which is also installed using cordova cli.

```
<feature name="Camera">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

When I click the camera Button, I find the navigator.camera object as undefined. I have tried it on couple of phones and it seems to be the same issue. I tried remote debugging using chrome and it also shows the camera object as undefined.

Cordova.js load fails with following object as undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'require' of undefined (cordova.js)

```
//Export for use in node
if (typeof module === "object" && typeof require === "function") {
  module.exports.require = require;
  module.exports.define = define;
 }
```

Cordova.js version is 3.7.1 .

Please note :Commenting these 3 lines from Cordova.js in platform_www seems to fix the issue. But i am wondering if someone can help suggest whats wrong here. Modifying the lib is the last option.

Answer (score 6):

the problem could be with the declaration of a variable named `module`, in my case it was

```
var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen']);
```

just rename module in something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test hybrid app on browser without proper tools. Use ripple chrome extension to test your app.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en

Comment: Thanks but as I said this is occurring on the phone. I am remote debugging the cordova as webview in chrome to see the problem (using chrome://inspect and connecting the phone in usb debugging). Without debugging also using alert logs in the App show the same error.